# Are Sandbox In App Purchases counted in Firebase analytics?

Tags: flutter, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

I am developing a app with Flutter and currently testing it on TestFlight. There are In-App-Purchases inside the app and for some reason last week on 3 different days my In-App-Purcheses went up ~1500%. I have no idea why so the only explanation is that Firebase might also track purchases of sandbox users.

So the question: **Does Firebase Analytics track Sandbox IAP as regular purchases? Is there any way to distinguish them within Firebase?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently yes, they are. Would be nice if there was an option to disable Sandbox-purchases, like in RevenueCat.